# How to resolve conflict when use yum install

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

I built and installed some libraries into my CentOs 7.9. I guess I used --prefix=/usr when I configured. However, I found the version of the source code was inappropriate. So I decided to install the package by yum install. But I saw conflicts when I run this command. Seemed the libraries in the package are older than what was installed. I couldn't use yum remove to remove what had installed. Because they were not installed from the package. How to resolve the conflicts or force yum to install the package?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. when u install it from source code

If u want to uninstall the package which was installed from source, actually it's hard to delete all the files u have installed when u put them in /user directory. But there is method: when the installation is finished, usually there is a 'install_mainfest.txt' file in your installation directory which logs all the files the installation generates.

so read this file, and delete all the files using:

```
xargs rm < install_manifest.txt
```

#### 2. when u install it using yum install

Find all the rpm package then delete them using:

```
rpm -qa|grep "your software name u wanna delete"|xargs yum -y remove
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I didn't find install_manifest.txt. I guess I might see it if the library is built by cmake.